# XSL transform: Get value of an attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to display the value of location attribute shown below in an excerpt of the source data:

```
<svrl:failed-assert test="cda:manufacturedMaterial/cda:code/@codeSystem = '
2.16.840.1.113883.6.88' or cda:manufacturedMaterial/cda:code/@codeSystem = 
'2.16.840.1.113883.6.59' or cda:manufacturedMaterial/cda:code/@codeSystem =
'2.16.840.1.113883.6.96'" location="/*[local-name()='ClinicalDocument' and
namespace-uri()='urn:hl7-org:v3']/*[local-name()='component' and namespace
-uri()='urn:hl7-org:v3']/*[local-name()='structuredBody' and namespace-uri(
)='urn:hl7-org:v3']/*[local-name()='component' and namespace-uri()='urn:hl7
-org:v3'][11]/*[local-name()='section' and namespace-uri()='urn:hl7-org:v3'
]/*[local-name()='entry' and namespace-uri()='urn:hl7-org:v3'][1]/*[local-n
ame()='substanceAdministration' and namespace-uri()='urn:hl7-org:v3']/*[loc
al-name()='consumable' and namespace-uri()='urn:hl7-org:v3']/*[local-name()
='manufacturedProduct' and namespace-uri()='urn:hl7-org:v3']">

        The value for manufacturedMaterial / code in a product template SHOULD  
        selected from the RxNorm (2.16.840.1.113883.6.88) code system for medicaTions,   
        and from the CDC Vaccine Code (2.16.840.1.113883.6.59) code system for 
        immunizations or MAY be selected from ValueSet 2.16.840.1.113883.1.11.20.8 
        MedicationTypeCode STATIC 200017.

</svrl:failed-assert>
```

I have the following transform:

```
<xsl:template match="schematron-output/failed-assert">
    <b><xsl:value-of select="text()/svrl:failed-assert/@test"></xsl:value-of></b>
    <b><xsl:value-of select="text()/svrl:failed-assert/@location"></xsl:value-of></b>
</xsl:template>
```

The value of the test and location attribute does not display. All that displays is:

```
The value for manufacturedMaterial / code in a product template SHOULD  
selected from the RxNorm (2.16.840.1.113883.6.88) code system for medicaTions,   
and from the CDC Vaccine Code (2.16.840.1.113883.6.59) code system for 
immunizations or MAY be selected from ValueSet 2.16.840.1.113883.1.11.20.8 
MedicationTypeCode STATIC 200017.
```

I have tried a couple of functions like `text()` to extract the value but haven't got anything working.

Comment: There is an error in `select="text()/svrl:failed-assert/@test"`. If you are referring to the element you posted it should be: `select="@test"`. The same with `@location` (use `select="@location"`). But since no `<b></b>` were printed, there are probably other errors (you might need to declare namespaces). Please post your full XSL or at least the templates and variables involved.

Comment: Post your source as well. If your files are too big, post at least the context of the nodes your are selecting (root nodes, significant nodes). It's also important that you show the namespace headers. The element names in the `match` and `select` attributes will have to be prefixed if the source declares them in a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account that you have the namespace properly declared-

```
        <b><xsl:value-of select="@test"/></b>
        <b><xsl:value-of select="@location"/></b>
```